# Github Pages Security, From .com to .io

Tags: csrf, session-management

Github pages is now using github.io domain instead of github.com I've read [github explanation](https://github.com/blog/1452-new-github-pages-domain-github-io) but it's still difficult for me to understand the root cause. Why would a domain become a security issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTTP cookie mechanism [allows you to specify the domain](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3) a particular cookie is associated with. The domain can be the domain of the page setting the cookie or, more interestingly, one of its superdomains. E.g. `foo.bar.example.com` is allowed to set cookies on the `foo.bar.example.com`, `bar.example.com` and `example.com` domains.

What does this mean for GitHub Pages? Well, subdomains of the `github.com` domain are allowed to set cookies on it, meaning they can perform [session fixation attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) by providing the browser with an existing session cookie. Here's how a simplified attack scenario would look:

Let's say `github.com` uses a cookie called `SESSION_ID` to identify active sessions. This cookie contains a unique hash, long enough to be impossible to to guess. Each hash is associated with server-side session data, i.e. a logged-in user.

Now consider an attacker who sets up a GitHub Page at `evil.github.com`. They include some of their evil scripts in the page and then trick a victim to visit it. What does the page do? It sets the `SESSION_ID` cookie on the `github.com` domain to a valid value known to the attacker. This would cause the victim's browser to effectively log in to GitHub *using the credentials provided by the attacker*. The attacker could then follow the activity on the account and retrieve any data created by the clueless victim.

Moving GitHub Pages from `github.com` to `github.io` fixes the issue, since there are no user accounts or sessions on the new domain.

Comment: thank you for your brief explanation. Another question arise: is this issue would affect any other user-generated subdomain? Example wordpress.com/blogger.com and so on. Or this vulnerability only applies to GitHub pages since only at GitHub pages, an attacker could write malicious code.